# Display data in table when geographic feature is selected

Tags: d3.js

Good Morning
Phil Pedruco's http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/7557092 is the answer to the inverse of my question. I am curious how to click on a geographic location, like one of the Irish counties and have the appropriate row in the table highlighted. or maybe better yet, have only the one row that contains the county information displayed. Thanks for any help -- Lovely work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First take rows declaration outside d3.csv callback as we need access to it in the click function:

```
var g = svg.append("g"), rows;
```

Set active class on the rows to indicate they will be visible:

```
// create a row for each object in the data
            rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                    .append("tr")
                    .attr('class', 'active');
```

In click function lets remove active class from all the rows then get the row corresponding to the selected county and set active class on it:

```
d3.selectAll('tr.active').classed('active', false);
        rows.filter(function(r){
            return r.County === d.properties.name;
        })
        .attr('class', 'active');
```

On reset lets add active class back to all the rows to make them visible:

```
d3.selectAll('tbody tr').attr('class', 'active');
```

Here is the result: http://bl.ocks.org/ckothari/96248a1cf4efff934600c1d1f1e6d9b4

Comment: I'll try this. I think this is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you for the quick response!!!

Comment: great! if this answers your question, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the tick next to the answer.

Comment: Hello -- I tried putting my data (csv & json) in. I used Maryland coordinates and the map is not displaying. Would you be able to take a look at my work? I think I am very close :-) What would be the best way to send it?

Comment: How about create a jsfiddle.net with your problem and create a question?